# How to create an offline repository for nuget packages in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have many .nupkg files downloaded and I don't always have an internet connection. So I'd like to change the nuget repository (nuget.org) to Eg. D:\nugetOffline. In that folder I'll put the .nupkg files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this using `%APPDATA%/Roaming/NuGet/NuGet.Config` and adding a config item like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <config>
      <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="C:\dev\nuget\packages" />
      <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\dev\nuget\packages" />
   </config>
</configuration>
```

You can also control this on a per solution basis using a NuGet.Config file in the same folder as the .sln file, and/or per project by placing a NuGet.config next to the .csproj file.

See the [NuGet.config file reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) for more details about all the available options.

For **globalPackagesFolder** (projects using PackageReference only):

The location of the default global packages folder. The default is %userprofile%.nuget\packages (Windows) or ~/.nuget/packages (Mac/Linux). A relative path can be used in project-specific nuget.config files. This setting is overridden by the NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable, which takes precedence.

For **repositoryPath** (packages.config only):

The location in which to install NuGet packages instead of the default $(Solutiondir)/packages folder. A relative path can be used in project-specific nuget.config files. This setting is overridden by the NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable, which takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio. In menu bar Tools -> Manage Nuget packages -> Package manager config -> Package origins. There is the nuget.org repo , click in Add and change the origin and name of the new repo, browse your folder and give a name , just click in update and accept. You can copy the .nupkg files in your selected folder